# How to execute a function if url contains "x" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, url, contains

I'd like to execute the function up(); if the url contains "invt".

So far I have this:

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/invt/"){
  alert("invt");
}
```

However, this wasn't alerting for me.  Any ideas?

I've since got this to work, thanks to the answers below.

Consider:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1) { //checks url for "invt" (all products contain this)
     up();
     return;
       }
      });
```

Comment: That's not **contains** - that means if it **is** `"/invt/"` with no text before or after. See answers below for usage of `.indexOf()`

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't realize this, I've since got it to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( window.location.pathname.indexOf('invt') >= 0 )
{
 alert("invt");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if (-1 != location.pathname.indexOf('invt')) {
    alert ("GO");
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/VphPc/)

Comment: Thanks :-) Very useful!  I only accepted dwaddell's because he was sightly faster, you both provided more than acceptable answers. :)

Comment: You're very welcome. That's perfectly OK: Always select the most suitable answer. It's not a race. :)